# vaadin-vertical-layout border styling for remove

Tags: css, typescript, vaadin, border

I'm using vaadin 23 components and customizing them on typescript.

I have to remove red highlighted borders of vaadin-vertical-layout, but I don't know how.

[image]

I've tried to use css styling almost on every component of html, but it didn't work.

I'm expecting that highlighted borders will be removed.

Answer (score 2):

You should probably find the CSS that is applying that border in the first place – it's definitely not there by default.

I recommend using the browser's dev tools to inspect the element and look through the styles that are applied to it, and then look for a corresponding style block in your project.